# Stretch div's evenly on rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I've got a lot of divs with a single image inside. The images are of different width, they have same height.
All the divs are float: left. This make them spread along multiple rows.

I would like to have the whole width of the site to be filled, so the div's should stretch accordingly.

I've tried to write some jQuery to run through all div's and adding pixels, but there are some missing and weird cases.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).imagesLoaded( function() {
        var items = $('.item'), row_width = $('body').width(), row_items = [], row_items_width = 0;
        $.each(items, function(i, el) {
            var item_width = $(el).width();
            if ((row_items_width + item_width) > row_width) {
                tmp_width = 0;
                $(row_items).each(function(j, elm2) {
                    if (j < (row_items.length - 1)) {
                        $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + Math.round((row_width - row_items_width) / row_items.length));
                        tmp_width += $(elm2).width();
                    } else {
                        $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + (row_width - (tmp_width + item_width)));
                    }
                });
                row_items = [];
                row_items_width = 0;
            } else if (i === items.length - 1) { // look at the very last item
                row_items.push(el);
                row_items_width += item_width;
                tmp_width = 0;
                $(row_items).each(function(j, elm2) {
                    if (j < (row_items.length - 1)) {
                        $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + Math.round((row_width - row_items_width) / row_items.length));
                        tmp_width += $(elm2).width();
                    } else {
                        $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + (row_width - (tmp_width + item_width)));
                    }
                });

            }
            row_items.push(el);
            row_items_width += item_width;
        });
    });
});
```

My idea is to run through div's and whenever I find one where the width gets bigger than the width of the site, I calculate and add pixel to the previous div's and then go on...

Am I overthinking this, can it be done more easily, perhaps with CSS only?
I've looked at plugins for jQuery, for example masonry, isotope etc., but they doesn't seem to fix that specific issue.

Comment: You want to find the widest of the images, and then set all of the image-containing `<div>` elements to that width?

Comment: No, the div's should have different widths. If there's 3 div's on the first row and for example 31px of white space left, then the two first should get 10px and the last 11px of extra width, so they become stretched 100 % of the rows width but are getting adding the same pixel, except a +/- 1 pixel for the last.

Comment: Can you provide an online demo of what you've so far, and describe you're issue based on that demo..? BTW, have you looked into css flexbox..?

Comment: I'll see if I can upload my demo some where... Currently everything is offline. I've tried to use flex box, without any luck.

Comment: Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/hensor/ghq2unaj/. I just used random images from Google search. Found out that looking at Google image search result actually are close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Any help? I would love to only use CSS such as flex box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix the issues. Just need heavy optimisation.

```
$(document).imagesLoaded( function() {
    var items = $('.item'), row_width = $('body').width() - 20, row_items = [], row_items_width = 0;
    $.each(items, function(i, el) {
        var item_width = $(el).width() + 60;
        if ((row_items_width + item_width) > row_width) {
            tmp_width = 0;
            $(row_items).each(function(j, elm2) {
                if (j < (row_items.length - 1)) {
                    $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + Math.round((row_width - row_items_width) / row_items.length));
                    tmp_width += $(elm2).width() + 60;
                } else {
                    $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + (row_width - (tmp_width + item_width)));
                }
            });
            row_items = [];
            row_items_width = 0;
        } else if (i === items.length - 1) {
            row_items.push(el);
            row_items_width += item_width;
            tmp_width = 0;
            $(row_items).each(function(j, elm2) {
                if (j < (row_items.length - 1)) {
                    $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + Math.round((row_width - row_items_width) / row_items.length));
                    tmp_width += $(elm2).width() + 60;
                } else {
                    $(elm2).css('width', '+=' + (row_width - (tmp_width + item_width)));
                }
            });

        }
        row_items.push(el);
        row_items_width += item_width;
    });
    $('.item').css('opacity', 1).css('-webkit-animation', 'fadein 2s');
});
```